# Magento2: How to get product description on product page

Tags: magento2

When I enter a given brand, then in the headline I have a description about this brand.
[image]

I would like to automatically download the description on the product card after entering the product from this brand.
[image]

**example:**

- When I open a product from the brand "mybrand1" get description from
  "brand1"
- When I open a product from the brand "mybrand2" get
  description from "brand2"

Any solution?

Comment: Is a brand a category?

Comment: Herve, you can check here:  https://czasowewyprzedaze.pl/shop-by-brand